# Is this definition of streamline motion really correct?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-energy, flow, bernoulli-equation

This is the definition that I have got in my textbook regarding streamline motion

> Streamline motion is the motion of fluids where particles flowing through a specific point have the same velocity at any given time

Basically that should mean that at any point in a streamline flow, any fluid particle that moves throught that point must have the same velocity at any time.
But I don't think this definition works for a tank with a hole at the bottom, where velocity of water flowing outside is $$\sqrt{\frac{2gh}{1-\frac{a^2}{A^2}}}.$$

Therefore $v$ is proportional to $h$
so as water in the tank decreases, velocity of water along the same streamline also decreases. So is this definition wrong?

Comment: "At a given time" and particle flowing "through a point." This is muddled language. More precise  langauge is "laminar flow" (meaning non-turbulent) or "steady flow" (meaning time independent). It is not possible to understand which your book's "definition" is intended to mean. Get a better book.

Comment: My guess is that “a given time” should be “**any** given time” - which is a slightly muddled way of saying that the flow is steady ($\partial \mathbf v/\partial t=0$).